# Where class, methods and its members are stored in memory?

Tags: java, memory, jvm

I have little doubt about where class, its methods(static and non-static), instance variables and reference variables are stores in memory(Heap, Premanent Generation in Heap, stack).

What i know is class, methods(static & non-static), static variable are stores in Permanent Generation in Heap. Instance variables and objects are stored in Heap. Method local variables and parameters are stored in Stack.

Correct me if i am missing something !

Thanks!

Comment: What are you exactly trying to ask?

Comment: You are telling right ..? b'cuz i didn't get a question here.

Comment: Are you asking or telling?

Comment: I am just asking you all to correct me if i am wrong, Thanks for commenting over here.

Comment: You *are* missing a lot. What you have named are some naive, bare-bones defaults and there's a lot more complexity to it. On another level, you are missing that it's quite irrelevant most of the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a question that relate to JVM, here I have a good article to explain about it, let's study together:
[JVM - Jamesdbloom blog](http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html)

[image: JVM memory]
Image source: http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/images_2013_11_17_17_56/JVM_Internal_Architecture_small.png

Comment: Thanks Rugal for this diagram !

Comment: @akash746 also the link I provide is rather important!!