# how are class variables represented in memory?

Tags: java, class, variables, memory, reference

Hi I have a pretty basic question about java class variable types and how they appear in memory. I understand that class variables hold references to an object in memory. However my question is how does the class variable appear in memory before it is used to hold a reference to an object. They way I picture class variables is that they are memory addresses that hold memory addresses. I don't know if that makes sense but if someone could help me clarify this basic concept I'd appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/a/21074408/1266600?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where class, methods and its members are stored in memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074341/where-class-methods-and-its-members-are-stored-in-memory)